# update nginx 1.4.4 to 1.4.5 trying to overwrite X which is also in package Y

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt, dpkg

I get this error while trying to upgrade:

```
Preparing to replace nginx 1.4.4-4~raring (using .../nginx_1.4.5-1~raring_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement nginx ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.4.5-1~raring_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx-full 1.4.4-4~raring
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.4.5-1~raring_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm using these repos:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ raring nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ raring nginx
```

Why is this file in nginx and nginx-full? I thought nginx-full depends on nginx?

Does anyone know why this happens and how to resolve it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nginx-full package isn't from "http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/" repository, it is from Ubuntu main repository.

Remove nginx-full (from main repo) before installing nginx (from nginx repo).

Keep in mind you will have problems with the `include` directive in the `nginx.conf` file, you need to change the line `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` to `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf` after install.

You can use apt pinning to avoid this problem by giving more priority to nginx package from nginx repository over the default ubuntu repository.

Take a look here: http://www.argon.org/~roderick/apt-pinning.html

Comment: I just did a apt-get remove nginx-full nginx-common, apt-get upgraded nginx from nginx's repository automatically. Thanks!

Comment: Created /etc/apt/preferences.d/nginx and added:
Package: *
Pin: origin nginx.org
Pin-Priority: 600

Comment: Indeed, this works as expected. I updated repo and then removed `nginx-full` and `nginx-common`. Then, when I installed `sudo apt install nginx=1.9.5*` it asked me if I wanted to use new conf or keep my existing one. Very handy tool. Thanks NGiNX for being awesome~